# Add Quotes to CSV Export

Tags: php, csv

I'm exporting data to a CSV file using `fputcsv`. I have strings that are being written however I have a requirement that the data is wrapped in double quotes.

```
foreach ($orderDetails['lines'] as $line) {
     fputcsv($orderImportCsv, $line);
}
```

This creates the following when opened in an editor (sublime)

> L,M3344,,100
>
> L,M3356,,50

I need to have each of these fields wrapped in double quotes.

So I have tried this:

```
foreach ($lines as &$line) {
    foreach ($line as &$column) {
        $column = '"' . $column . '"';
    }
}
```

So essentially this should go through each lines fields and wrap it in "". However after running that I get the following output:

> """L""","""M3344""","""""","""100"""
>
> """L""","""M3356""","""""","""50"""

It's now putting 2 sets of double quotes around the variable!

Is there a better way to do this?

**UPDATE**

I know `fputcsv` has two optional parameters. Delimiter and enclosure. However I believe enclosure defaults to "" but only when the string is split into separate words.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you insert the enclosure yourself, you have to instruct PHP to use none. There doesn't seem to be a documented way to do it, but using a space seems to work:

```
<?php
foreach($orderDetails['lines'] as $line){
    foreach ($line as &$column) {
        $column = '"' . $column . '"';
    }
    unset($column);

    fputcsv($orderImportCsv, $line, ',', ' ');
}
```

Or you can just avoid [fputcsv()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php) and compose everything yourself.

Comment: This workaround definitely does the trick, HOWEVER, it's annoying that fputcsv() adds extra spaces around everything when " " is used as the $enclosure param, yet doesn't allow an empty string as the $enclosure itself.

Comment: Hah! You helped me twice! I would like to vote up the second time, cause the last time this answer helped me at 28 April 2022, and today a year later you saved my day again <3

Answer (score -1):

This is just normal, if you create CSV file using Excel and enclose one cell with double quota, then, it will added others to the source file, for example:

This is how CSV appears in Microsoft Office Excel 2007:

```
"
""
"""
""""
"""""
```

Source code:

```
"""",
"""""",
"""""""",
"""""""""",
"""""""""""",
```

Then nothing goes wrong, as you can see the first example in the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php):

```
<?php

$list = array (
    array('aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc', 'dddd'),
    array('123', '456', '789'),
    array('"aaa"', '"bbb"')
);

$fp = fopen('file.csv', 'w');

foreach ($list as $fields) {
    fputcsv($fp, $fields);
}

fclose($fp);
?>
```

The above example will write the following to file.csv:

```
aaa,bbb,ccc,dddd
123,456,789
"""aaa""","""bbb"""
```