# fputcsv() add quotes to every entry?

Tags: php, csv, export-to-csv, fputcsv

With this code I create my CSV export file:

```
foreach ($data_for_export as $row) {
    $data = [];
    array_push($data, $row->product_id);
    array_push($data, $row->product_name);
    array_push($data, $row->product_code);
    array_push($data, $row->text);

    fputcsv($file, $data);
}

fclose($file);
```

Example output is:

```
2131,"Toys set 35", TSSET35, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet"
```

I tried it with:

```
    preg_replace("/([a-z0-9]+)/i", '"$1"', $row->product_id)

    '"'.$row->product_id.'"'
```

With "preg_replace" I get some times more quotes then needed...

I need there quotes on all export items, how can I do that?

Comment: Why are quotes on all items a requirement? CSV doesn't require it as such, which is why PHP isn't adding quotes to items that don't need it.

Comment: @deceze it's customer requirement :(

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Convert all data to string by **strval** function, then try to use **[fwrite](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fwrite.php)** instead of **[fputcsv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php)**:

```
function push(&$data, $item) {
    $quote = chr(34); // quote " character from ASCII table
    $data[] = $quote . addslashes(strval($item)) . $quote;
}

foreach ($data_for_export as $row) {
    $data = [];

    push($data, $row->product_id);
    push($data, $row->product_name);
    push($data, $row->product_code);
    push($data, $row->text);

    // separate array items by ',' and add the End-Of-Line character
    fwrite($file, implode(',', $data) . PHP_EOL); 
}

fclose($file);
```

Comment: You might also need to escape any existing quotes in the `$item` variable.

Comment: I forgot that, thanks for your attention. Code edited.

Comment: Here is the best solution solution:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15133892/add-quotes-to-csv-export

You can use fputcsv, but you have to configure the enclosure to blank. Than you add manually quotes where you want.